# octomap to a 2d map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

from ros.org, it said "octomap_server loads a 3D map (as Octree-based OctoMap) and distributes it to other nodes in a compact binary format". so how can i convert those binary format to a real 2d pmg format map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61414/octomap-to-a-2d-map/) by [unknown](https://answers.ros.org/users/4599/unknown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While not documented anywhere, I have an octo_to_2d utility in the map_tools package of my [sandbox repository](https://github.com/mikeferguson/sandbox). This will take a COLOR octomap in .ot format, take a slice at a specified height, and publish an appropriate map. You can then use map_saver to save the map. The source code is pretty self documenting as far as parameters and topics.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-25**:
The octomap_server should be able to do that out of the box (not sure about color octomaps).